# UTF-8 Width Display Issue of Chinese Characters

Tags: c, perl, unicode, utf-8, vertical-alignment

When I use Perl or C to `printf` some data, I tried their format to control the width of each column, like

```
printf("%-30s", str);
```

But when str contains Chinese character, then the column doesn't align as expected.
see the attachment picture.

My ubuntu's charset encoding is zh_CN.utf8, as far as I know, utf-8 encoding has 1~4 length of bytes. Chinese character has 3 bytes. In my test, I found printf's format control count a Chinese character as 3, but it actually displays as 2 ascii width.

So the real display width is not a constant as expected but a variable related to the number of Chinese character, i.e.

```
Sw(x) = 1 * (w - 3x) + 2 * x = w - x
```

w is the width limit expected, x is the count of Chinese characters, Sw(x) is the real display width.

So the more Chinese character str contains, the shorter it displays.

How can I get what I want? Count the Chinese characters before printf?

As far as I know, all Chinese or even all wide characters I guess, displays as 2 width, then why printf count it as 3? UTF-8's encoding has nothing to do with display length.

Comment: In other words, you're looking for a multibyte-aware version of `printf` for Perl and/or C?

Comment: I've never done utf8 decoding in C but here's a Go code that counts runes in an utf-8 string : http://golang.org/src/pkg/unicode/utf8/utf8.go?s=4824:4876#L202

Comment: @dystroy It isn’t just a matter of counting the code points (i.e., runes). Rather, it is taking into account that different code points represent 0, 1, or 2 print columns per UAX#11, and this is fairly subtle, especially with the `East_Asian_Width=Ambiguous` characters. I don’t know of any Go library that deals with this the way the Perl library described in my answer does, but if there is such a thing for Go, I’d love to learn about it! Thanks.

Comment: @tchrist : I learned something. And I just made a test : "go fmt" doesn't format correctly structs with "long" characters. So I guess there are still imperfections is Go's handling of the gigantic beast that is Unicode...

Comment: Display width (number of screen positions), number of characters and number of bytes are three different things. `printf` only cares about the number of bytes. If you want to take into account the number of characters, use `wprintf` (remember, it takes a `wchar_t*` format). There's no formatting function in C that takes into account display width.

Comment: @n.m. Dealing with physical code units instead of logical code points is always a major fail.

Comment: @tchrist: that's what the specification of `printf` says. Perhaps a better one is in order.

Comment: @n.m. Depends whose `printf`
.  Some deal in code points.  None deal with print widths.

Comment: @tchrist: `printf` is defined by the C standard, any deviation from it is, well, non-standard.

Comment: @n.m. Immaterial. Read the fourth word in the original poster’s question.  Only the C `printf` is defined by the C standard, **no one else’s.**  Certainly Perl’s `printf` wouldn’t be so stupid as to treat characters as bytes, and doesn’t. Neither does Ruby’s `printf`, nor Java’s `printf`, nor Go’s `fmt`, nor Python’s `%` operator. I’m sure there are plenty of other langauges with a modern character processing model that aren’t crippled by bytethink.

Comment: @tchrist: sorry I should have made clear that I'm only talking about C, not Perl or anything else.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is a problem with all versions of `printf` that I am aware of. I briefly discuss the matter in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072795/471272) and also in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372126/471272).

For C, I do not know of a library that will do this for you, but if anyone has it, it would be ICU.

For Perl, you have to use the [Unicode::GCString](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aGCString) module form CPAN to calculate the number of print columns a Unicode string will take up.  This takes into account [Unicode Standard Annex #11: East Asian Width](http://unicode.org/reports/tr11/).

For example, some code points take up 1 column and others take up 2 columns.  There are even some that take up no columns at all, like combining characters and invisible control characters. The class has a `columns` method that returns how many columns the string takes up.

I have an example of using this for aligning Unicode text vertically [here](http://training.perl.com/scripts/perlunicook.html#PROGRAM:-Demo-of-Unicode-collation-and-printing). It will sort a bunch of Unicode strings, including some with combining characters and “wide” Asian ideograms (CJK characters), and allow you to align things vertically.

[image: sample terminal output]

Code for the little `umenu` demo program which prints that nicely aligned output, is included below.

You might also be interested the far more ambitious [Unicode::LineBreak](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aLineBreak) module, of which the aforementioned `Unicode::GCString` class is just a smaller component. This module is much cooler, and takes into account [Unicode Standard Annex #14: Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/).

Here’s the code for the little `umenu` demo, tested on Perl v5.14:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl
 # umenu - demo sorting and printing of Unicode food
 #
 # (obligatory and increasingly long preamble)
 #
 use utf8;
 use v5.14;                       # for locale sorting
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use warnings  qw(FATAL utf8);    # fatalize encoding faults
 use open      qw(:std :utf8);    # undeclared streams in UTF-8
 use charnames qw(:full :short);  # unneeded in v5.16

 # std modules
 use Unicode::Normalize;          # std perl distro as of v5.8
 use List::Util qw(max);          # std perl distro as of v5.10
 use Unicode::Collate::Locale;    # std perl distro as of v5.14

 # cpan modules
 use Unicode::GCString;           # from CPAN

 # forward defs
 sub pad($$$);
 sub colwidth(_);
 sub entitle(_);

 my %price = (
     "γύρος"             => 6.50, # gyros, Greek
     "pears"             => 2.00, # like um, pears
     "linguiça"          => 7.00, # spicy sausage, Portuguese
     "xoriço"            => 3.00, # chorizo sausage, Catalan
     "hamburger"         => 6.00, # burgermeister meisterburger
     "éclair"            => 1.60, # dessert, French
     "smørbrød"          => 5.75, # sandwiches, Norwegian
     "spätzle"           => 5.50, # Bayerisch noodles, little sparrows
     "包子"              => 7.50, # bao1 zi5, steamed pork buns, Mandarin
     "jamón serrano"     => 4.45, # country ham, Spanish
     "pêches"            => 2.25, # peaches, French
     "シュークリーム"    => 1.85, # cream-filled pastry like éclair, Japanese
     "막걸리"            => 4.00, # makgeolli, Korean rice wine
     "寿司"              => 9.99, # sushi, Japanese
     "おもち"            => 2.65, # omochi, rice cakes, Japanese
     "crème brûlée"      => 2.00, # tasty broiled cream, French
     "fideuà"            => 4.20, # more noodles, Valencian (Catalan=fideuada)
     "pâté"              => 4.15, # gooseliver paste, French
     "お好み焼き"        => 8.00, # okonomiyaki, Japanese
 );

 my $width = 5 + max map { colwidth } keys %price;

 # So the Asian stuff comes out in an order that someone
 # who reads those scripts won't freak out over; the
 # CJK stuff will be in JIS X 0208 order that way.
 my $coll  = new Unicode::Collate::Locale locale => "ja";

 for my $item ($coll->sort(keys %price)) {
     print pad(entitle($item), $width, ".");
     printf " €%.2f\n", $price{$item};
 }

 sub pad($$$) {
     my($str, $width, $padchar) = @_;
     return $str . ($padchar x ($width - colwidth($str)));
 }

 sub colwidth(_) {
     my($str) = @_;
     return Unicode::GCString->new($str)->columns;
 }

 sub entitle(_) {
     my($str) = @_;
     $str =~ s{ (?=\pL)(\S)     (\S*) }
              { ucfirst($1) . lc($2)  }xge;
     return $str;
 }
```

As you see, the key to making it work in that particular program is this line of code, which just calls other functions defined above, and uses the module I was discussing:

```
print pad(entitle($item), $width, ".");
```

That will pad out the item to the given width using dots as the fill character.

Yes, it’s a lot less convenient that `printf`, but at least it is possible.